# In JavaScript, if “Strings are objects” then why not Numbers too?

Tags: javascript

You can do

```
"a".charAt(0);
```

wouldn't it be nice if you could do:

```
42.isMeaningOfLife();
```

well, or rather something more practical like

```
myNumber.round();
```

Sure the first thing that crossed my mind is that this would be a performance hog but apparently that is not how the JS compiler works. Check this [MDN article on JS strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects):

> Note that JavaScript distinguishes between String objects and
>   primitive string values. (The same is true of booleans and numbers.)
>
> String literals (denoted by double or single quotes) and strings
>   returned from String calls in a non-constructor context (i.e., without
>   using the new keyword) are primitive strings. JavaScript automatically
>   converts primitives to String objects, so that it's possible to use
>   String object methods for primitive strings. In contexts where a
>   method is to be invoked on a primitive string or a property lookup
>   occurs, JavaScript will automatically wrap the string primitive and
>   call the method or perform the property lookup.

Comment: You can `(42).isMeaningOfLife();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it's a simple matter of supported syntax. Both, strings and numbers are wrapped in their respective object wrapper (`String`, `Number`) when performing *objects operations* on them.

```
Number.prototype.isTheMeaningOfLife = function () {
    return this.valueOf() === 42;
};

(42).isTheMeaningOfLife(); //true
42.0.isTheMeaningOfLife(); //true
```