# Why are Strings and Numbers in JS considered immutable?

Tags: javascript, immutability

I am bit confused, Wikipedia (I know, I know) defines immutability as

> [immutable object is an object whose state cannot be modified after it is created.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)

while the JS implementation example states

> [In JavaScript, some built-in types (numbers, strings) are immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#JavaScript)

I understand now that in JS [both Numbers and Strings are Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604044/in-javascript-if-strings-are-objects-then-why-not-numbers-too) but why would they be considered immutable when I can clearly change the value of any Number or String variable?

Comment: You "change" by creating a *new* string or number, not by *modifying* the original

Comment: You are talking about assigning different values to variables.

Comment: `var x = 42` assigns an immutable number/value 42 to your variable. if you do `x++`; then the 42 is destroyed and replaced with a new immutable number: 43.

Comment: You can't change the value of e.g. 8 or 23 or "puppies!".

Comment: `'foo'[1] = 'a'` - nope.

Comment: The string/number is immutable. The variable you're storing it in is not.

Comment: Notice that also booleans, `null` and `undefined` are immutable. Though it's most noticable with strings, which could be seen as a composite value.

Comment: does that mean that I can change value of property of immutable object? If str1="abc";str1="xyz"; did not mutate the str1 variable then how about obj1.str1="abc";obj1.str1="xyz"?

Comment: That is no different from assigning values to variables. I don't see how assigning property values has anything to do with mutating strings even if it were possible.